# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running Scala JUnit Test on Scala IDE (Eclipse Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, scala, junit

I've recently decided to install Scala IDE 3.0.3 (which is basicly Eclipse Kepler with scala plugin). I've newest specs (specs2_2.10-23.11), scalaz (2.10-7.0.4), collection (scalaj-collection_2.10-1.5) and scala library [2.10.4]

I tried to run my tests in scala using "Scala JUnit Test" but i got this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalaz/concurrent/Strategy$   at
>   org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ExecutionStrategy.scala:43)
>     at
>   org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ExecutionStrategy.scala:41)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)  at
>   org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(ExecutionStrategy.scala:41)
>     at
>   org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(ExecutionStrategy.scala:38)
>     at scalaz.syntax.IdOps$class.$bar$greater(IdOps.scala:15)   at
>   scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps$$anon$1.$bar$greater(IdOps.scala:78)    at
>   org.specs2.reporter.JUnitReporter$class.report(JUnitReporter.scala:44)
>     at org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner$$anon$4.report(JUnitRunner.scala:43)
>     at org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner.run(JUnitRunner.scala:50)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   scalaz.concurrent.Strategy$   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 17 more

What causing that? I probably missing something but I can't find what.

My tests are running just fine with gradle.

Comment: Did you use the `eclipse` gradle plugin to generate your project?  If so, did the addition of `spec2` occur after originally generating the project?  Do you see those jars under the `Reference Libraries` section of your project?

Comment: i didnt use gradle plugin so thats not a point and I see those jars in this section :/

Comment: Do you also see those jars under the test's run configuration classpath tab under the `User Entries` section?

Comment: In general, when I have problems with Eclipse's classpath it's either that I don't have the jars I think I do, or I have too many in the wrong order.  Since you have the jars, maybe it's the latter?  Otherwise, I'd suggest designing a minimal project to replicate the error and link it here.

Comment: Well i found solution. I missed scalaz-concurrent, which somehow is not in scalaz-core.

Comment: Using the `eclipse` gradle plugin to generate the project in the first place might have caught that.  It's dependendent on whether or not the sources you're requesting having up-to-date pom files etc.  And you have use that plugin to regenerate the project any time you change dependencies in the build.gradle file.  But it can take some fiddling and it's not for everyone.  Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well meaby someone will find it helpfull. I find solution: I missed `scalaz-concurrent` jar which apparently is not included in `scalaz-core`. Note that you need the same version of `core` and `concurrent` in order to work.